# Are sub-SELECT's in SELECT and FROM clauses standard-compliant?

Tags: sql, select, subquery, ansi-sql

The title pretty much says it all.  Under "standard-compliant" SQL I mean SQL constructs allowed in any of SQL standards.

I looked through the "Understanding SQL" book, but it mentions subqueries only inside `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` etc. clauses, not `SELECT` and `FROM` (or maybe I'm missing something).

I know MS SQL allows sub-SELECT's in `SELECT` and `FROM`.  I would like to know if it is a standard behavior.  Or maybe it isn't standard, but is now implemented in major SQL databases (I have very little experience with DB's other than MS SQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use a subquery as a derived table wherever you can use a table in a select statement.

[SQL ANSI 92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

Comment: Thank you, especially for "derived table" term.  I also searched for it in a late draft of SQL:2003 standard and indeed, in "Foundation" part, section 7.6 it states that any <table reference> (which then used in the definitions of SELECT and FROM clauses) can be <derived table>.

Comment: Be nice if the downvoter could have the courtesy to comment on downvoting a correct answer....